# Remove the line break after a <label>

Tags: html

My form is formatted by a 2 column table.
In the left column I use a `<label>` and in the right column a `<input type="text">`.
Some of the input boxes are required.
So the requirement is that for all the compulsary inputs, there should be a red asterisk next to the label.
However a label is designed so that it is always followed by a line break, so the asterisk automatically goes underneath.
What is the best way of making sure this does not happen, and the asterisk goes in the correct place next to the label?
I do not think the `<div float="left>` option would work in a table.
This is the code as requested;

```
<tr>
                <td class="leftCell"><span style="white-space: nowrap;"><label for="Subcontractor_CompanyName">Company</label><span style="display: inline;" class="errorHighlight">*</span></span></td>
                <td class="rightCell"><input style="width: 300px;" id="Subcontractor_CompanyName" name="Subcontractor.CompanyName" value="096 club" type="text" data-val-required="Must enter the Company Name" data-val="true">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="false" data-valmsg-for="Subcontractor.CompanyName">*</span></td>
            </tr>
```

My attempt at using a `<span style="white-space: nowrap;">` failed.

Comment: change the elements to `display: inline;`, at the minute they are block, which means they hog the line to themselves (no element is followed by a line break, they are just inline or not)

Comment: Useful to know that, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Or, if they have given the `<label>` as block, you can do this way:

```
label {display: inline;}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to change the markup, you can place the asterisk within the label.

Something like:

```
<label>Name:<sup>*</sup></label>
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

And CSS:

```
label sup { color: red; }
```

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/ByGVE/

Answer (score 2):

A label will not, given default browser default CSS and enough width to hold the input next to it, trigger a new line.

You probably have some CSS that sets `display: block` on the label. Set that on the input instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use style="white-space: pre-wrap;"