# How do I mismatch D3's closing tag?

Tags: d3.js

I would like to build the following radio buttons procedurally.

```
<input type="radio" name="bees">5<br />
<input type="radio" name="bees">10<br />
<input type="radio" name="bees">20
```

If I use code such as the following:

```
function build_colony() {
    const bees_list = [5, 10, 20];
    d3.select('.colony)
      .selectAll('input')
      .data(bees_list)
      .enter()
      .append('input')
      .attr('type', 'radio')
      .attr('name', 'bees')
      .text(d => d);
}
```

I get a closing `</input>`:

```
<div class="colony">
    <input type="radio" name="bees">5</input>
    <input type="radio" name="bees">10</input>
    <input type="radio" name="bees">20</input>
</div>
```

How do I mismatch D3's closing tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want your text nested within your input.  So, I'd use a placeholder `span` to handle my data-binding so that your `input` and `label` can be siblings.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="colony"></div>
  <script>
    let bees_list = [5, 10, 20];
    
    var s = d3.select('.colony')
        .selectAll('span')
        .data(bees_list)
        .enter()
        .append('span');

      s.append('input')
        .attr('type', 'radio')
        .attr('name', 'bees')
        .attr('id', d => d);
        
      s.append('label')
        .text(d => d)
        .attr('for', d => d);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your approach is cleaner, for sure, but it also sometime introduces undesirable line breaks that are tricky to dodge.

Comment: @Vrokipal, can you elaborate on what you mean by *undesirable line breaks*?   My runnable snippet above has no line breaks.

Comment: Add the style `.colony { width: 200px; }` and replace the first assignment with `let bees_list = d3.range(30).map(d => 2**d);`. Then some of the inputs will be separated from their labels.

Comment: Ironically, the flexibility of these alternative styles is facilitated by your more correct solution. It's somewhat of an orthogonal issue, for which one can find a multitude of mediocre solutions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14608156/9295807 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/512769/9295807